# Where does user order get recorded in OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to find the controller responsible for saving orders to the user's record after checking out. Which one would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders are first added to the database in the file `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`. This is called by the final page of the checkout, which is `/catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php` on the default checkout. However, this just sets up what's referred to as a 'missing order' which is an order where the `order_status_id` value is set to `0` - due to the order not currently marked as paid. Once the customer pays, the payment gateway used will update the order setting the correct order status. You can find all of the payment gateways in `/catalog/controller/payment/`